# QML memory management

Tags: garbage-collection, qml, qt5

I'm trying to test QML to understand how it works with C++. I have `ClassA` and `ClassB` - 2 similar C++ classes. Here is a `ClassA`. All methods are self explanatory with their names, so I won't place implementation here.

```
class ClassB;
class ClassA : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ClassA(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~ClassA();
    Q_PROPERTY(ClassB* classB READ getClassB WRITE setClassB NOTIFY classBChanged)
    ClassB* getClassB() const;
    void setClassB(ClassB *classB);
signals:
    void classBChanged();
private:
    ClassB *m_classB;
};
```

`ClassB` is the same, just change all `*lassA*` to `*lassB*` and all `*lassB*` to `*lassA*`.

Then I register both classed in QML with

```
qmlRegisterType<ClassA>("testmodule.test",1,0,"ClassA");
qmlRegisterType<ClassB>("testmodule.test",1,0,"ClassB");
```

And in `QML` code on mouse click I create both objects like this:

```
onClicked: {
    var comp = Qt.createComponent("TClassA.qml"); //TClassA.qml is 
                                                  //a component of type 
                                                  //ClassA
    var ca = comp.createObject();
    comp = Qt.createComponent("TClassB.qml");
    var cb = comp.createObject();
    ca.classB = cb;
    cb.classA = ca;
    parent.blockFromGC = ca;
}
```

And after that I call garbage collector with `gc()`. I expected that `ca` is blocked from removal with `parent.blockFromGC` and `cb` is blocked from removal with reference from `ca`. But garbage collector destroyed `cb` and after that `parent.blockFromGC.classB === null`.

So I have second `MouseArea` with this code:

```
onClicked: {
    console.log(mouse.button)
//    if (mouse.button == Qt.RightButton) {
//        console.log(parent.vasya.classB)
//    }
    gc();
    console.log(parent.blockFromGC.classB) //I use cb here
}
```

So when I click the `MouseArea` I get in console:

```
qml: 1 //Left button
qml: null //value of parent.blockFromGC.classB
classB destroyed:  TQMLClassB(0x34960d0) //I have qDebug() in destructor
```

So my object `cb` was destroyed.

So I have this questions:

1) Is there a way how I can register a `C++` type as basic type, so I could
write `var ca = new ClassA()` instead of creating a `*.qml` file, creating a component and finally creating an object?

2) Why did garbage collector destroyed my `cb` object and what should I do
to keep this object from deleting?

Moreover! If I uncomment those commented lines

```
//    if (mouse.button == Qt.RightButton) {
//        console.log(parent.vasya.classB)
//    }
```

regardless the button I press, the object is not destroyed anymore.

```
qml: 1 //left button
qml: TQMLClassB(0x3df8e90) //object is alive
.....
qml: 2 //right button
qml: TQMLClassB(0x3df8e90) //before gc() - alive
qml: TQMLClassB(0x3df8e90) //after gc() - alive
```

3) Where can I read about `QML` memory management in detailes? I find this behaviour really strange..

Addition 1: I played with this situation a bit more and the results were unpredictable. I updated from 5.3 to Qt 5.4 and this behavior with object deletion has gone. The problem is that the behavior was so unpredictable, that the fact I can't reproduce this behavior in Qt 5.4 doesn't mean that the problem is fixed. I'll try to look in bug reports and bug fixes. If I found something, I'll post it here. If not, I'll try to reproduce this situation in Qt 5.4 and post a report.

Comment: You can put `ClassA` decraration inside a `Component` and so create it through `var ca = thisComponent.createObject(parent)`. As for objects destruction - can you make sure at which step the desctructor was called? As I know an object can be destructed if there aren't references to it so you have to seek out in this way.

Comment: @folibis In debug mode this problem became a probability problem. Some times it happened and sometimes didn't. The trace didn't give me much information. All function calls were done, as expected, in shared libs and some of them were hidden. And all of them has quite usual names for the functions that try to delete and object. Anyway, read an addition to post and thanks for your advise how can it be done without creating *.qml file.

Answer (score 4):

1. Like any QML type, you can define a component statically within another:

   ```
   Component {
       id: classAComponent
       ClassA { }
   }
   onClicked {
       var ca = classAComponent.createObject()
   }
   ```
2. There is a subtlety here: assigning a QML object to a QML `property` will increase its JavaScript ref-count. But an instance stored **only** in the Q_PROPERTY of a C++ object won't be marked by the garbage collector.

   QML has a dual ownership system. First it defines a hierarchy of QObject/QQuickItem used for display and ownership. Attached to this backbone is a garbage collection system where any QML object can own a tree of JavaScript objects through `property var`.

   So to keep your ClassB object alive, you either have to keep it in a **QML** property, or provide a parent for it when calling component.createObject() (it's a hard ownership; it will be destroyed regardless of any JS reference to it when the parent is destroyed)

   Example with the QML property:

   ```
   Component {
       id: classAComponent
       ClassA {
           property Item refClassB
       }
   }
   onClicked {
       var ca = classAComponent.createObject()
       ca.refClassB = classBComponent.createObject()
   }
   ```

   Ideally you should avoid dynamically creating object as much as possible and use your C++ objects statically like normal QML components and let the declarative structure maintain the QObject backbone automatically, like this:

   ```
   ClassA {
       classB: ClassB { }
   }
   ```
3. Sadly not so much, the best I know of, more for QML than C++ is [Dynamic QML Object Creation from JavaScript](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html).

Comment: 1) Thanks. This way is much nicer than I did. 2) I wrote in Addition that in new version of Qt this situation doesn't behave like I described. And under debug it was random in prev. version. Moreover if someone creates an object he shouldn't care how component was described (QML or QObject). I hope it was a bug and now it is fixed and hope "But an instance stored only in the Q_PROPERTY of a C++ object won't be marked by the garbage collector" is now not true. =)